# SysTrayIcon and Recursive/loop function

Tags: python, recursion, infinite-loop, system-tray

I'm having a bad time trying to create a simple program that runs in the notification area using the [SysTrayIcon](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/SysTrayIcon.py.html)

While I can insert the program and start it, I can't manage to Quit/Suspend it from the the tray icon, because my program is in loop using a while True or a recursive function.

```
from systray import SysTrayIcon
from time import sleep

def program(SysTrayIcon):
    print "I'm Stuck in the loop!"
    sleep(1)
    program(SysTrayIcon)

menu = (('Start', icon.next(), program),)

SysTrayIcon(icon.next(),"Tray",menu)
```

It runs with no problem, when I click Start, it does what it have to do, in the case, print "I'm Stuck in the loop!" every 1 second, but I can't click to Quit.

Any hint?

Comment: You normally want some condition in your function that determines whether or not to recurse.  Something like `if break_condition: return` as the first line, but this particular code snippet is a bit ambiguous as to what you're attempting to accomplish.

Comment: I can't think any other way to do this.

The code I'm trying to run, have to be in a infinite loop, I could do it using a 'while True' but I find it to be less readable. 

The program works just fine, except that I can't kill it in the tray icon, I have to kill it througt the task manager.